# Remove '¶' character from R saveWidget output

Tags: html, r, pandoc, quarto

I'm generating a reactable object and saving it in a HTML widget with saveWidget function, my code is like this: (qmd document)

````
```{css, echo = FALSE}
.tag {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px 12px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 12px;
      overflow-y: scroll; 
      height:400px;
    }
```
````

Generate and save table:

````
```{r}
library("reactable")
library("htmlwidgets")

reactable(data = data_table,
            class = "tag",
            filterable = TRUE,
            rownames = FALSE,
            selection = "multiple",
            showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
            paginationType = "jump",
            showSortable = TRUE,
            highlight = TRUE,
            resizable = TRUE,
            rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"),
            onClick = "select") %>%
    saveWidget(., 
               "table_name.html", 
               selfcontained = T, 
               libdir = "lib"
               )
```
````

My problem is: when I open the output ("table_name.html") there's a string with "¶¶¶¶¶¶", I don't know how to remove it.

This is how it looks:
[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/448

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the link in the comments, this is fixed in the widget. However, if one should run into this in a different context, then on could also use a [Lua filter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html).

```lua
local sep = pandoc.Inlines{pandoc.Space(), pandoc.Str '¶', pandoc.Space()}
function Inlines (inlines)
  for i = #inlines - 2, 1, -1 do
    if pandoc.Inlines{inlines[i], inlines[i+1], inlines[i+2]} == sep then
      inlines:remove(i+2); inlines:remove(i+1); inlines:remove(i)
    end
  end
  return inlines
end
```

Save the above to a file, say `remove-pilcrow.lua`, and use it with

```yaml
---
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: ['--lua-filter=remove-pilcrow.lua']
---
```

in R Markdown or

```yaml
---
filters:
  - remove-pilcrow.lua
---
```

in Quarto.